# Mask Bridge with Road

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, symbology, representation, esri-production-mapping

Is there a tool to create mask between bridge line/point on road? The requirement to have gaps 0.2mm between road and bridge and the offset fill with white color. For now, I add a white line attach to bridge symbol but the result not that great. Looking for improvement and better result.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: for the point put a white box marker symbol in the marker, for the line add a layer of the width then draw the bridge before the road. Can you modify the production mapping symbols?

Comment: If adding white box marker, the white marker will cross the road. If do the layer arrangement which is bridge layer under road, when there is situation where the bridge near a junction, part of bridge symbol will be hide. Yes user can edit the representation or do some free representation but the requirement is try to less any manual editing work

Comment: Either modify the symbol or draw the bridges first as a white mask, then roads and finally bridges as their symbol.

Comment: Arc Representation has a tool for underpasses. http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00700000002m000000

Answer (score 2):

ESRI provided an exercise for using geoprocessing tools for representation. In the final steps it demonstrates the process for masking and shows the results.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000005n000000

I hope this helps!